# How to draw Probability Density Function using line plots in IDL?

Tags: plot, statistics, distribution, idl-programming-language

I have a vector containing values and I would like to draw a probability density function (PDF) graph for the values contained. Let's say I have a vector given by `b=[1,1,3,4,5,2,3,5,1,4,2,4,1,1,4,2,3,5]`. I can draw a histogram as follows

> cghistoplot, b, binsize=1, xtitle='values', ytitle='freq', /fill

[image]

However, I want to draw the pdf using a line plot, i.e. I want y values to be normalized by the number of values in the vector (18 here). I know I can use `cgplot` to make line plots, but it needs x- and y-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `HISTOGRAM` built-in routine like the following:

```
hist = HISTOGRAM(b,BINSIZE=1,LOCATIONS=locs,MIN=0,MAX=6)
```

Then you can plot the results doing something like:

```
PLOT,locs,hist,PSYM=10,XTITLE='values',YTITLE='freq'
```

This will show a quick and easy histogram form.  If you want a line plot, just remove the `PSYM` keyword setting.

Comment: thanks for your input; however, I wanted the y values to range from 0 to 1, since it represents probability. I did this after creating the `hist` as you did above: `pdf=float(hist)/n_elements(b)` then `p_pdf=plot(locs,pdf,xtitle='values',ytitle='freq')`

Comment: @Bereket - Then just normalize `hist` by `TOTAL(hist)` to get relative occurrence rates for each bin.

Comment: yep, that's essentially what I did. Thanks!